# Windows 7 won't recognize backup set can I script extracting the files in some other way?

Tags: windows-7, backup, external-hard-drive, restore, script

The Windows 7 Backup/Restore created multiple backup sets and I was able to restore the oldest version, but not the most recent, which is not seen by the application.

I do see all of the zip files and there are hundreds in later versions. Is there a way to extract each of these correctly outside of the regular restoration method? Perhaps scripting an extract of each day  one after another?

**further clarifying**
  The backup files were all made to an external drive. The original computer died completely, power supply, drives everything. I am trying to reconstruct as much as possible and the only backup set recognized is 6 months older. This was recovered over a new install, but unzipping thousands of zip files is not really a simple unzip copy project as the original paths are not a simple thing to reconstruct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/how-do-i-manually-extract-files-from-file-backup/97e2ecde-fe58-44e1-a70b-5927461271a4), but basically, windows backup is a zip archive.

Comment: +1. Use WinRAR. Select all, right-click, "Extract all"

Comment: the link isn't found.  & @Ian Boyd My problem with right-clicking and extracting these is that there are well over a thousand. Is there a simple way to extract each one in sequence?

Comment: Winrar can extract all of them at once. just select all. And link fixed, there was an extra bracket, sorry.

Comment: I believe this may actually be a solution for my solution, since the paths are preserved

Comment: How can you retrieve a full backup together with all of the incremental backups using this technique?  It seems like incremental backup creates a lot of partial files that need to be merged in.